# Install OpenOffice from cmd line Redhat Linux 6

Tags: rhel, openoffice

I stupidly removed OpenOffice from my work laptop and have not managed to re-install it .

As it is a work laptop, I have no internet access (just intranet) so I can't download it directly.

I downloaded the repository of OpenOffice from a YUM server but can't get OpenOffice to open any spreadsheets.

Any ideas where to go from here?

Just some more information: I used `yum install openoffice` and then checked that the rpm was there by typing `rpm -q openoffice`. Also the `openoffice` directory is there but I think that's from the original install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 : Download the appropriate version**

For 32 bit Version download this from terminal: 
`wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-rpm_en-US.tar.gz/download -O Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-rpm_en-US.tar.gz`

For 64 bit version download this from terminal : `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-rpm_en-US.tar.gz/download -O Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-rpm_en-US.tar.gz`

**Step 2 : Change to root User**

```
su -
```

### OR

```
sudo -i
```

**Step 3 : Remove OpenOffice.org if any**

```
yum remove openoffice*
```

**Step 4 : Extract Package and Access Directory**

```
tar -xvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1*

cd en-US
```

**Step 5 : Block openoffice.org-ure and libreoffice-ure package updates**

In other words, “pin” openoffice.org-ure and libreoffice-ure packages
Add exclude row to `/etc/yum.conf` file, under the section [main]:

```
## Edit file
nano -w /etc/yum.conf



## Add exclude row

[main]

exclude=openoffice.org-ure*
```

**Step 6 : Install / Update Apache OpenOffice 4.1.1 RPM packages**

```
rpm -Uvh RPMS/*.rpm RPMS/desktop-integration/openoffice4.1.1-redhat-*.rpm
```

**Step 7 : Start Apache OpenOffice 4.1.1**

Start OpenOffice with Clicking Icons (found normally from menus) or Start OpenOffice with Following Command:

```
openoffice4
```

Comment: @Anthon , I have updated the answer with the detailed information.

Comment: Krishnadas PC Thanks that got it back working.So all is good with the world :)